# Switching 24V and GND with MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, actuator

I need to control motion direction of linear actuator. It works off of 24V power supply, and if i switch polarity of supply it goes to opposite direction. The supply for actuator is simple DC with no PWM.

I try to switch power to actuator with this circuit:

[image: schm]

Basically actuator has two terminals which connected (through SSR) to **OUT_H** and **OUT_L**. **U4** is the simple inverter and **U3, U5** gate drivers. The **DIR** signal goes from MCU and control direction of motion. 
I assume that when the **DIR = 0** i would have **OUT_H = 24V** and **OUT_L = 0V**, when **DIR = 1** - **OUT_H = 0V** and **OUT_L = 24V**.

Is my assumption is right for this kind of application, or i'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The part you chose, [IR21844](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/ir2184.pdf) is a half-bridge driver, so it's designed to work in only one direction (polarity).  It's also not specifically designed as a motor drive.  Depending on your actuator, it may or may not be suitable.  The easy answer would be to use a full [H-bridge driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge) that can handle polarity reversal for you, such the [L6201](http://www.st.com/internet/analog/product/63228.jsp). That will save parts, time, and headaches.

If you can't change parts for some reason, you'll need to an extra set of MOSFETs controlled by the microcontroller to provide the remainder of the H-bridge circuit.  Have a look at the block diagram for L6201 to get an idea of how to wire up the MOSFETs.

On a minor note, your schematic is backwards.  Usually people draw them with inputs (`DIR`) on the left, and outputs on the right.

Comment: But if i have only one driver, and IN = 1, the top mosfet will be switched on and voltage at it's source will be 24 V, that's ok, but bottom mosfet will be off at that time so i can't provide ground path for current in this case. So that's the primary reason i put two drivers, so the bottom mosfet on second driver connects the load to ground.

Comment: My apologies. On a second glance, the part does not work how I thought it would. Edits to follow.

Comment: These bridges are designed for class D (PWM) or Stepper motor mode and not linear.

Comment: @jbarlow: yeah, thanks for the tip, but unfortunately my application needs 10A constant DC current to flow through the bridge, and i can't find similar ICs that can handle that much current. Also, it seems that circuit that i presented will not work at all because the upper mosfet can't be open for a long time because bootstarp capacitor (**C6 and C10**) will be discharged, and i need to turn on lower mosfet to charge it again. I find this app note [link](http://www.irf.com/technical-info/designtp/dt92-4.pdf) about this issue, but i think this also overcomplicates thing alot.

Comment: @elk: The H bridge I suggested is a circuit topology, not an IC.  You didn't specify current consumption was quite high given the voltage, so I suggested an IC.  You should be able to use power MOSFETs in series or better, relays, to achieve direction control.

Answer (score 0):

Bridge Amps with MOSFET drivers do not work very efficiently in Linear mode. (non PWM)
Class AB Audio Amp is preferred and Class D Audio Power Amp is best ( PWM mode).

If you want to design one choose Class AB Bridge Linear Amp chips.
If this is for high power Linear actuator, may I suggest the Crown DC300 in surplus circulation.

A Linear Voice Coil is basically a speaker with a lower impedance due to mechanical mass.
They were the de facto method of large disk drive actuators since the 60's until rotary actuators became popular in the 80's. Several Hp Linear Motors could move a large mass an inch in 50 mS and with servo feedback stop with 0.001" of desired target.

Here is a low end 40W bridge Amp for a few dollars
[image]  [REF](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00001662.pdf)  It has some sophisticated protection circuits with zero pop on switch and mute.  You can bypass the input Caps and drive DC differential or single ended input but you must null an DC offset with your pre-amp. This Amp is 40W in 3.2 Ohm with 30 dB gain.

CLass D is best for high power for savings on heat, driver and power supply costs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i think that i can't use this amp, because on the inputs **IN+** and **IN-** i will have DC signal, but the schematics chows that inputs must be AC coupled. Also on the load i need 24V DC @ 10A.

Comment: no   "You can bypass the input Caps and drive DC differential or single ended input but you must null an DC offset with your pre-amp."